# How to change vue elements order

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have this object structure:

```
lines: [{ 
  order: '1', 
  text: ' blue' 
},{
  order: '2', 
  text: 'green' 
},{ 
  order: '3',   
  text: 'yellow' 
}]
```

And this is rendered on the page like this:

```
Blue
Green
Yellow
```

I want reorder the elements (and the object) without drag-drop, but with button up and down. Like this:

```
Blue - [down]
Green [up, down]
Yellow [up]
```

Each bullet is a component. How can I achieve that?

Comment: well first off you should use a number for order instead of a string.

Comment: It's ok. I know it. I do not know how to do it

Comment: The array has index

Comment: There's just no way to answer this question.  It is incredibly broad and incredibly unclear.

Answer (score 4):

Based on assumptions from the little information you provided, I gave it a go.

Read: [Vuejs list caveats](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats)

From the documentation:

> Due to limitations in JavaScript, Vue cannot detect the following changes to an array: 
> When you directly set an item with the index, e.g. `vm.items[indexOfItem] = newValue`

So when you modify an array in Vue you should use one of the following:

```
// Vue.set
Vue.set(example1.items, indexOfItem, newValue)
// Array.prototype.splice
example1.items.splice(indexOfItem, 1, newValue)
```

Your view can look something like:

```html
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(line, index) in lines">
    <p style="display: inline-block">{{line.text}}</p>
    <button @click="up(index)" v-if="index !== 0">UP</button>
    <button @click="down(index)" v-if="index !== lines.length-1">DOWN</button>
  </div>
</div>
```